# exponential curve fit on histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram, curve

I made a histogram in R and I have to fit an exponential curve on it.

[image]

But the curve doesn't appear on the histogram.

This is the code:

```
hist(Adat$price, main="histogram",xlab="data")
curve(dexp(x, rate=1,log=FALSE), add = TRUE)
```

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add set the argument `freq=FALSE` if you want the histogram to be normalized:

```
set.seed(32418)
sim <- rexp(100) + rnorm(100,0,.01)
hist(sim, freq=FALSE)
curve(dexp(x, rate=1, log=FALSE), add = TRUE)
```

[image: hist output]

Otherwise, the height of the bins will be a function of the number of samples. In fact, the curve technically *did* appear on your graph, it's just so small that you can't distinguish it from a flat line at y = 0.